# How to prevent uib-modal updating live page content

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an issue using UI Bootstrap's modal instance and I know it's something I'm doing wrong, I just can't work out what.

I start with a button that creates a new instance of `talker` and passes it to my `modalInstance`:

```
     $scope.newTalker = function( type ) {

        // Create a new instance of the talker
        var talker = {};



        // Set some default talker options
        talker.type = type;
        talker.showReduced = true;



        // Launch the modal
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            backdrop: 'static',
            templateUrl: 'templates/modal.talker.new.tpl.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
            controller: 'TalkerModal as vm',
            resolve: {
                talker: function() {
                    return talker;
                }
            }
        });

        ...
        ...
     }
```

This then passes into another view and builds a page based on data passed back from my modal - all good.

However, my problem is that on my view I have an edit button that I want to allow users to edit the data stored in `$scope.talker` (the data returned from the modal).

I am passing back in `$scope.talker` to the modal to allow users to edit the original details:

```
    $scope.editTalker = function() {



        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            backdrop: 'static',
            templateUrl: 'templates/modal.talker.new.tpl.html?bust=' + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
            controller: 'TalkerModal as vm',
            resolve: {
                talker: function() {
                    return $scope.talker;
                }
            }
        });

        ...
        ...
     };
```

My modal controller looks like this where I am assigning the passed in talker to `vm.talker`:

```
.controller( 'TalkerModal',
    function( $uibModalInstance, $timeout, talker ) {



        var vm = this;



        vm.submitted = false;
        vm.numRowsError = false;
        vm.talker = talker;
        vm.titleLocked = true;
        vm.showPriceEntry = false;
        vm.quantity = 1;

        ...
        ...
```

However, I am finding that when users edit data in the modal, it is updating the view live in the background.  Even if the user clicks on cancel, all the changes have already been committed to the page.

To put my example into a live perspective, look at the following example https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/8U4TIT.
 As you edit a name on the modal, you can see it updates live in the background.

How can I prevent this?